# Autowire not working for bean inside prototype bean

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am building a REST service API's and from the REST Controller i would like to call another implementation class.
From MyController i am creating a bean of ServiceImpl and the ServiceImpl uses the Customer object. (Just for testing customer is expected to be singleton).
I am trying to access a bean inside a prototype bean but it fails with Null Pointer.

---

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    static int i = 0;
    public MyController() {
    System.out.println("Inside Controller");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public int post(ServiceImpl impl) {
    return impl.name(i++);
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Customer {

    String name;

    public Customer() {
    System.out.println("inside customer cons");
    }

    public String getName() {
    return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }

}
```

---

```java
@Configuration 
public class ServiceConfigurations {

    @Bean
    public Customer Customer() {
    return new Customer();
    }   

}
```

---

```java
@Component
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public class ServiceImpl {

    int i = 0;

    @Autowired
    Customer c;

    public int name(int name) {
    c.getName();  // Fails with null pointer
    return i++;
    }

}
```

Can some one help as to why @Autowire for Customer is not setting the reference?

Comment: Have you tried using constructor injection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is your *false* *expectation*.
These lines

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public int post(ServiceImpl impl)
```

don't actually `@Autowire` a new `ServiceImpl` Bean, they simply create a new instance of `ServiceImpl`. No injection is being performed at all.

For an overview of Bean scopes, and how to use them, see [Spring Bean scopes](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried @Autowire the ServiceImpl in the Controller but that just makes it singleton and not prototype. How can i get a new instance on every request

Comment: Thanks. Fixed the problem. Added a bean of request scope and in the controller added the @Resource.

Comment: @CPF that's good! You can also use Autowired in place of Resource